# Initializing objects at run-time

Tags: java, hashmap

**EDIT:**

It seems as though I have not been clear enough in what I'm asking for, I'm going to try to explain better.

I have a class called `Board`

This class will have a 2-dimensional array filled with integers, each integer value in the array corresponds to some class (so 1 could be short-hand for String for example).

This class will also have some means to take this 2-dimensional array, loop over it and create new instances of some classes.

I need to be able to customize what the 2-dimensional array and what classes the different integers corresponds to.

I did a little image to try to visualize what I want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mSvN.png

Along with some pseudo-code:

```
class Board:
   Integer[][] some_array = {{1,2,1},{1,2,1}}
   someStructure = {1 : createThing, 2 : createSomeOtherThing};

   generateObjects():
        List[Thing] container = []
        for y in some_array:
            for x in y:
                container.add(someStructure[x]())
        return container
```

**OLD FORMULATION:**

I have a class called `Map` which is supposed to contain an `Integer[][]` object, the values inside the Integer array object corresponds to some object which will need to be initialized.

Now, in a language like Python I could for example have a dictionary which has some integer values as keys and some functions which creates and returns new objects when called and then loop over a 2d-list and call the functions returned by the dict. How would I go about to do this with Java?

I though about having a HashMap and doing some kind of reflection but I don't really know what to do tbh.

Comment: This sounds like a Guava `Cache`...

Comment: So the goal here is to go through the array and every time you see 1 you call function1(), 2: function2() etc?  If so, is there a reason to not use a switch statement?

Comment: Well, a switch-case would be fine if I wouldn't have several objects which has different requirements and integer values.

Comment: maybe some pseudo code? It's still not crystal clear to me what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: It might help to have context on the limits of your application. If you only have a limited number of classes that you want to instantiate, something along the lines of theglauber's answer should work. If you want more generality, it sounds like a job for [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't have closures or pointers to functions, but you can have a series of classes that implement an interface, and each class would have a method (say, a method called "run", or "makeObject", whatever makes sense in your context). These methods would create the different objects you need. You can store those classes in your dictionary.

Here's some quick and dirty pseudocode, not tested:

```
/**
* root for your object hierarchy
*/
public class MyObject
{
    // yadayada
}

/**
* The interface
*/
interface ObjCreator
{
    public MyObject makeObject();
}


/**
* Classes to create specific objects
*/
public class ObjMaker_1
    implements ObjCreator
{
    public MyObject makeObject()
    {
        return new Object1();
    }
}

...

public class ObjMaker_n
    implements ObjCreator
{
    public MyObject makeObject()
    {
        return new Objectn();
    }
}



/** your dictionary */
Map<Integer, ObjCreator> dict = new HashMap<Integer, ObjCreator>();

dict.add(new Integer(1), new ObjMaker_1);
dict.add(new Integer(2), new ObjMaker_2);
...
dict.add(new Integer(n), new ObjMaker_n);
```

If the object creation functions are short and simple, it's probably best to populate the dictionary with anonymous classes instead of fully defined classes.

Comment: I'm not really sure how I'd go about to implement this, care to give me some keywords for Googling/searching around StackOverflow?

Comment: I added some pseudocode. If the creation functions are short/simple, you can populate your dictionary with anonymous classes instead of fully defined classes.